# Custom template in sales (Magento2)?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7, grid-layout, custom-template

I want to create a template file in **sales->order->create new order** for showing custom comment.
so i create a template file set in `sales_order_create_index` layout.
But It not displaying in admin order creation form.

**In layout file(sales_order_create_index.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="billing_method">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Xxx_Order::order/create/billing/method/form.phtml" name="order_create_billing_form" as="form" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

It only showing after reloading that form.

If any changes in my layout file. I've checked the code but can't find the problem. Anyone can help? Thanks.